# Scroll doesnt locks with overflow: hidden

Tags: modal-dialog, scroll-lock

I want to lock scroll when modal is open. I add to body overflow: hidden, but that doesn't help.

I also install js lib scroll-lock that do almost same thing.

Here is a shot of that magic https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg4SW.jpg

How to lock scroll?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding by additinal height: 100vh